# How to Access ext3/ext4 (Ubuntu 14.04) Partition from Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I have recently installed **Windows** (10) on my **Ubuntu** (14.04) alongside after shrinking the root partition ( **/dev/ubuntu-vg/root** ) using GParted live (terminal) and rearranging the partitions using GParetd Partition Editor (GUI).

But now I cannot access root partition from Windows using **Ext2Fsd**. Here is my partition list.

[image]

**/dev/ubuntu-vg/root** is not in the Partition list and I think it is some where inside the **/dev/sda5**. **Ext2Fsd** identifies the file-system of this partition as **RAW**.

Please let me know if there is a way to access this Partition from Windows 10.

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question. IMHO you should ask at Windows sites how to access `ext` partitions. And also I am afraid that lvm partitions can't be accessed from Windows. And what is the point of accessing linux system partitions from Windows?

Comment: I think Ubuntu community can help me with this. Some Ubuntu users may have experienced the same issue. And I am using Ubuntu as my Main OS therefore I have to access files in Ubuntu partitions (Specially Images and Videos) from Windows. (I am using softwares like Aftereffects)

Comment: You can create an NTFS partition and share there files you need to acces both from Windows and Linux. Or do not use lvm.

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do it. This are the best two ways.

1- If you want to show the ext partition in my computer use "Ext2Fsd"

for download  [Click here](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16)

You can have Ext2Fsd launch at every boot or only open it when you need it. While you can theoretically enable support for writing to Linux partitions, I haven’t tested this. I’d be worried about this option, myself – a lot can go wrong. Read-only support is fine, though, and doesn’t have a risk of messing anything up.

If you didn’t set Ext2Fsd to autostart at boot, you’ll have to go into Tools –> Service Management and start the Ext2Fsd service before you can access your Linux files. By default, the driver automatically mounts and assigns drive letters to your Linux partitions, so you don’t have to do anything extra.

2- If you want to explore your ext partition in an app use "Ext2explore"

It’s an open-source application that works similarly to DiskInternals Linux Reader — but only for Ext4, Ext3, and Ext2 partitions. It also lacks file previews, but it has one advantage: it doesn’t have to be installed; you can just download the .exe and run it.

The Ext2explore.exe program must be run as administrator or you’ll get an error – you can do this from the right-click menu. To save some time in the future, go into the file’s properties window and enable the “Run this program as an administrator” option on the Compatibility tab.

As with Linux Reader, you’ll have to save a file or directory to your Windows system before you can open it in other programs.

For download [Click here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RonnieDroid but Ext2Fsd identifies the file-system of this partition as RAW. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: This is because of lvm.

Comment: It seems there is no way to access logical volumes from windows @Pilot6

Comment: Ext2explore is unstable on windows 10